# Unable to send POST request in Python

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I have to make a POST request with the following url, headers and payload respectively:

```
https://mywebsite.com/ui/rest/rule/


{'Cookie': 'R_A=MXF0OWVobmQ0dKDDIzMg==; UUID=6f75b02d-db9b-4968-aebe-851ab50e8fsf8:117683d280706807411', 'X_CSRF_Token': 'MXF0OWVobmQ0ddDIzMg==', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}


{"existingGroupIds": [], "existingUserIds": [], "role": {"assetPermissions": [], "name": "check", "clientId": 141, "description": "b"}, "removedGroupIds": [], "removedUserIds": [], "addedGroupIds": [], "addedUserIds": []}
```

Below is my function which makes the network call. Please note that payload is passed to sendRequest() as a dictionary. self.getHeaders() also returns headers as a dictionary.

```
def sendRequest(self,payload):
    r=requests.post(self.getUrl(),data=simplejson.dumps(payload),headers=self.getHeaders())
    html=r.text
    if (r.status_code==200):
        print "Request successful"
    else:
        print "\nRequest failed. Status code: %s"%(r.status_code)
```

The problem is that I always get the output as "Request failed. Status code: 401" which means "Unauthorized". But when I take the same url, headers and payload, and use POSTMAN/Advanced Rest Client to send the request, I get a 200 OK. Is my implementation of requests.post() wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your `requests.post()` call, no. There is something else that is different; you could post to `http://httpbin.org/post` instead and inspect the returned JSON response to see what different headers are sent, the server you are contacting *probably* is varying it's response based on one or more of those differences.

Comment: Tip: you don't need `simplejson.dumps()`. First of all because Python comes with a `json` module installed (which is the same codebase), and second because `requests` can send JSON natively by using `json=` instead of `data=`.

Comment: You are hard coding the cookies?